# Error putting S3 policy: AccessDenied: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have this defined policy to enable public access

policy.json.tpl:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-static3/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

s3.tf:

```
locals {
  s3_static  = "test-static3"
}
resource aws_s3_bucket s3-static-bucket {
  bucket = local.s3_static
}
# Static

data "template_file" "s3-static-policy_1" {
  template = file("policy.json.tpl")
  vars = {
            bucket = "test-static3"
  }
}

resource aws_s3_bucket_policy s3-static-bucket {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3-static-bucket.bucket
  policy = data.template_file.s3-static-policy_1.rendered
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3-static-bucket.id

  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "s3-static-bucket-public-access-block" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3-static-bucket.id
  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
  depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3-static-bucket ]
}
```

Ive added the required IAM permissions to allow s3:GetBucketPolicy and s3:PutBucketPolicy. I have no permission restrictions but still getting this error.

> │ Error: Error putting S3 policy: AccessDenied: Access Denied
> │       status code: 403,
> │   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3-static-bucket,
> │   on s3.tf line 16, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3-static-bucket":
> │   16: resource aws_s3_bucket_policy s3-static-bucket {

Comment: You can verify permission in the IAM policy simulator.  In that you can find the issue if any in your permission

Comment: Double checked the permissions and they are all approved for creating policies

Comment: Could it be the order of operations, such that it is attempting to add the policy before disabling `block_public_policy`?

Comment: That was actually it! can't believe I missed it. Thanks!